# Laptop sees memory cards as write-protected, while other computers don't, even after OS reinstall

Tags: windows, format, write-protect

I have 3 scandisk memory cards that Laptop A insists are write-protected, no matter what I do to remove the write protection. So far I have tried the following:

- Windows format: "The disk is write protected"
- HP USB Disk Storage Format Tool: "Device media is write-protected"
- Changing registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\StorageDevicePolicies to 0
- diskpart clear attributes readonly
- diskpart clean: "Diskpart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
- HDD Low Level Format Tool: "Format Error occurred at offset 985,595,904: 1117 - Device I/O error" and hundreds of similar errors

They originally were formatted in exFAT(when they first stopped working) but I've since formatted them via other windows 10 latops as NTFS.

Since these cards work fine and do not show up as write-protected on other computers, I'm assuming the problem is with Laptop A.

So last night I did a complete wipe of Laptop A's hard drive and reinstall of the OS....and it still sees the 3 memory cards as write-protected.

So now I wonder if its a hardware problem with Laptop A. However, since Laptop A can still read from the cards without a problem, I have a hard time believing this.

I'll also add that this problem started when I was quickly copying a lot of data using the cards from Laptop A to another Laptop. In the midst of this copying, Laptop A just stopped being able to write to any of them.

I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: So.. the other laptop is also running on Windows 10?
Same update version? Which format are the USB formatted in?
NTFS or FAT?

Comment: Yes both laptops are running Windows 10. Same update version. Memory cards were originally exFAT but I've since formatted them as NTFS. However Laptop A still says they are write-protected....even after the OS re-install.

Comment: Have you tried an external card-reader on the problematic laptop? Yoiu could borrow one or buy it for US$5 in some places.